# Dynamically selecting multiple values from XML in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have many large XML documents with totally different structure with many differing levels of elements that I want to select several dozen items from. The issue is there are many different document types in entirely different namespaces that I all have similar information. So I wanted to make the select data driven.

I have a table, let's call it `metadata`. Imagine f1 might be someone's name, f2 their account number, f3 a telephone number, etc.:

```
doctype    fldid     xpath    
---------  --------  --------------------------
abc        f1        /document/g/h[1]
abc        f2        /document/k/j/p/r/p[1]
abc        f3        /document/a/e/d[1]
def        f1        /info/d[1]
def        f2        /info/r/e/d[1]
def        f3        /info/e/s[1]
```

And we have the data table, called `mydatatable`:

```
docid    doctype    docfield
-------  ---------  ------------------------
1        abc        <document><n>.....
```

So I figured I could just do a query:

```
select 
    metadata.fldid as fldid, 
    mydatatable.docfield.value(metadata.xpath, 'nvarchar(max)') as data
from 
    mydatatable
inner join 
    metadata on mydatatable.doctype = metadata.doctype
where 
    mydatatable.docid = 1
```

I was expecting output:

```
fldid   data
------  --------------
f1      Tom
f2      344534534
f3      999-555-1212
```

But instead, I get this error:

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal.

So this means I need to know all the document structure ahead of time or I need to cursor through the metadata table and put the query into dynamic SQL in order to create this query?

Please note, I'm not talking about multiple nodes with the same element names. I'm talking about all different element names with differing (or similar) xpaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would need dynamic SQL to do this. But you do not need a cursor, just build up the query and execute it one go.

I think you could probably just build up a series of `if else` XQuery expressions, in your case the code would produce

```
if(sql:column("md.xpath") = "/document/g/h[1]") then '/document/g/h[1]'
else if(sql:column("md.xpath") = "/document/k/j/p/r/p[1]") then '/document/k/j/p/r/p[1]'
else if(sql:column("md.xpath") = "/document/a/e/d[1]") then '/document/a/e/d[1]'
else if(sql:column("md.xpath") = "/info/d[1]") then '/info/d[1]'
else if(sql:column("md.xpath") = "/info/r/e/d[1]") then '/info/r/e/d[1]'
else if(sql:column("md.xpath") = "/info/e/s[1]") then '/info/e/s[1]'
else ()
```

So you could use dynamic SQL like this:

> I've parameterized `@docid`, you don't have to do this, you could enter a literal like you hav done, but don't directly inject data from elsewhere.

> Note correct use of `QUOTENAME` to escape the strings

```sql
DECLARE @xq nvarchar(max) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
      'if(sql:column("md.xpath") = ' + QUOTENAME(md.xpath, '"') + ') then ' + QUOTENAME(md.xpath, '''')
      AS nvarchar(max)), '
else ')
      + '
else ()'
    FROM metadata md
);

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
select
  md.fldid,
  dt.docfield.value(''(
' + @xq + ''')[1]'',''nvarchar(max)'') as data
from mydatatable dt
inner join metadata md on dt.doctype = md.doctype
where dt.docid = @docid;
';

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing

DECLARE @docid int = 1;

EXEC @sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@docid int',
    @docid = @docid;
```

Comment: This can't possibly scale. There are more than 3 fields and more than 2 doctypes in the actual application. I expect there to be 200-300 entries in the metadata table. That if else will get extremely huge. And I didn't include in this question all the namespace juggling.

Comment: Also, I'm using SQL 2016. STRING_AGG is first available in 2017.